# Too many for loop iterations - for loop terminates

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, feature-selection

In a classification task, I need to do feature selection. So out of `featSize = 98` features (variables), I want to know which ones are applicable. For each combination I train the classifier by tuning its hyperparameters. I've come across a problem in my usage of a `for` loop:

```
  for b = 1:(2^featSize) - 1
        % this is to choose the features. e.g. [1 0 0] selects the first
        % feature out of three features if featSize = 3.

end
```

Matlab gives a warning: `Warning: Too many FOR loop iterations. Stopping after 9223372036854775806 iterations.`
Am I using the `for` loop in a prohibitive way? Is there another alternative method of completing this step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building a model for every possible combination of features is intractable. It's clear from your for loop that you would have to build an exponential number of models to cover every feature subset.

There are many approaches to feature selection that are practical to implement. The one most similar to your method is forward-selection. Many algorithms offer a regularization parameter instead (e.g. LASSO or ridge-regression). Some options for regression are discussed here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127444/a-guide-to-regularization-strategies-in-regression

This talk covers many approaches to the problem of feature selection https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JsArBz46_3s&index=21&list=PLGVZCDnMOq0ovNxfxOqYcBcQOIny9Zvb-&t=0s

Comment: thank you for answering with useful tips on machine learning aspect. Can you please mention if ensemble learning (not the AdaBoost) is a way to classify subsets of features using same learner or maybe different learners by doing feature subset selection nad then applying learners on each subset? the link for the explanation and implementation is here (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38944-ensemble-toolbox)

Comment: @SrishtiM No that's a separate question. you should ask it at https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

2^98 = 316.9e27 = 300 thousand million million million million. If you run a billion* loop iterations a second, it would take ten thousand million** years to run that loop. I don't think you can afford the electricity bill... :)

It is scary, isn't it, how quickly exponential things explode?

Luckily, you don't need to loop this often to visit all pairs of features. If you have 98 features, then you have 98^2 pairs, not 2^98. Actually, you have 98*97, if you don't want to pair a feature with itself, and 98*97/2 if the order doesn't matter.

You can write a double loop to visit each pair:

```
N = 98
for ii = 1:N-1
   for jj = ii+1:N
      % do something with the pair [ii,jj]
   end
end
```

<sub>* A billion as in a million million -- not the US billion.</sub>

<sup>** 2^98 /1e12 /60 /60 /24 /365 == 10.049e+9 -- I didn't take leap years or leap seconds into account... :)</sup>

Comment: OP isn't searching for the best pair of features but rather the best subset (of any size)

Comment: Assuming `featSize =3`, the reason I did the for loop as `2^(featSize)-1` is to get the following combinations: `[1;2;1 2;3;1 3;2 3]`. If I do the way you have mentioned which is  
`for b = 1:(featSize^(featSize - 1))
    
display(find(de2bi(b,featSize))); 
end;`, then Matlab throws the error:`Error using de2bi (line 163)
Specified number of columns in output matrix is too small.` Using each combination of subset, I train a learner.

Comment: @Dan: your mentalist abilities are better than mine, I guess. I missed that. :/

Comment: @SrishtiM: not sure what your code there is doing, why do you do `featSize^(featSize - 1)`? That is even larger than `2^featSize`!

Comment: Sorry, it will be multiplied and not raised to the power. Having said that, I am tuning on the best subset of any size as per Dan's explanation. Therefore, should the `for loop`  be doing `featSize*(featSize-1)` or the way I have done which is `2^(featSize)-1` which is also problematic due to the reasons mentioned by you and others.

Comment: @SrishtiM: if you want to explore all subsets of all sizes, you have `2^featSize` sets to go through. Use feature selection strategies as suggested by Dan in his answer. My answer was assuming you wanted to took at all pairs of features.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are requesting the for loop to do 2^98 = 316,910,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 iterations, so you will need to reduce the number of iterations.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, **yes, you are using the `for` loop in a prohibitive way, almost destructively**. It's absurd to ask any regular computer, much less a super computer to run that many iterations of a loop. So that is that part of your question answered.

Regarding developing another method of tackling this, I don't know much about machine learning (I guess this is bad to say as I'm attempting to solve this), but regardless, it doesn't seem like you've provided enough information for us to help you there. Either way, you will need to somehow **drastically** reduce the number of iterations of the loop for this to run efficiently, and avoid the error.